# what is right method for creating a menu in python kivy?

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I need to make a menu where you press a button and move to another layout with new elements. For example menu from 3 buttons: 'start', 'history', 'settings'. What is the way to realize it by python with kivy?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: right method: read documentation or tutorial.

Comment: Try looking at [kivyMD: How can I create dropdown menu with toolbar action item?](https://oursbrand.com/answer/python/kivymd-how-can-i-create-dropdown-menu-with-toolbar-action-item)

Answer (score 0):

To switch between screens you have to use: [Kivy Screen Manager](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html).

Short example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

Builder.load_string("""

<MyScreenManager>:
    StartPage:
        name: "start"
    HistoryPage:
        name: "history"
    SettingsPage:
        name: "settings"

<StartPage>:
    Label:
        text: "#1 Start Page"
        
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: 0.1

        Button:
            text: "Start"
            
        Button:
            text: "History"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "history"

        Button:
            text: "Settings"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "settings"

<HistoryPage>:
    Label:
        text: "#2 History Page"
        
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: 0.1

        Button:
            text: "Start"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "start"
                
        Button:
            text: "History"
            
        Button:
            text: "Settings"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "settings"

<SettingsPage>:
    Label:
        text: "#3 Settings Page"
        
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: 0.1

        Button:
            text: "Start"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "start"
            
        Button:
            text: "History"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "history"
            
        Button:
            text: "Settings"
            
    """
)


class StartPage(Screen):
    pass

class HistoryPage(Screen):
    pass

class SettingsPage(Screen):
    pass

class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class myApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyScreenManager()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myApp().run()
```